# Erro com ponteiro -Wint- conversion ?? Int para int *

Tags: c, ponteiro

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


 int *a;
 int  b;


int main()
{
  
 b = 5;

*a = &b;

printf("%x \n",a);
printf("%d",*a);

printf("\n %d",b);

return 0;
}
```

Na saída do código aparece esse erro :

> ```
> ponteiros.c: In function ‘main’:
> ponteiros.c:13:8: warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>      *a = &b;
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O formatador para um ponteiro é o `p` e não o `x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b = 5;
    int *a = &b;
    printf("%p\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    printf("%d", b);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qL3Nmv). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/ciyqbnvd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Format.c).